# cp: cannot create regular file : permission denied with runAsUser 1337

Tags: java, linux, spring, kubernetes, tomcat

when i am running my spring application in tomcat using .sh file in init-container in kubernetes and i have set runAsUser : 1337 in security context of the init-container in deployment.yaml file.

it gives

cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/java/openjdk-11/conf/security/java.security.bak': permission denied

and

sed: couldn't open temporary file '': permission denied.

i have used chmod to change permission but facing below issue

chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/jdk/conf/security/java.security': Operation not permitted

also facing

/startup.sh: line 3: exec: catalina.sh: not found

my .sh file (after adding chmod)

```
chmod -R 766 ${JAVA_HOME}/conf/security
/add-jce-provider.sh ${JAVA_HOME}/conf/security/java.security;
exec catalina.sh run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to write to the directory, then it is possible that:

1. the directory has the immutable flag enabled. check with lsattr.
2. the directory is mounted with read-only permissions: type in
   terminal: `cat /proc/mounts (or mount or cat /etc/mtab)`
   and check the output, if directory is mounted read-only.

If you are in the first case, change the directory attributes with `chattr`;

remove immutable flag on file or directory `chattr -i <file/dir>`

adding immutable flag on file or directory again `chattr +i <file/dir>`

If you're in the latter case, edit the file `/etc/fstab`.